# Difference between vector insert and assign

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I read that the assign method clears the vector target indexes before assigning anything to it.Does that mean if we have a vector such as:

```
vector<foo*> somevector;
```

then the assign method would actually delete foo* before copying data to the target indexes.

Comment: I don't think the destruction of the stored objects would happen before the copying, that would not be exception safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `std::vector` will never call delete on stored pointers.  It will simply destroy the object.  In the case of a class objects with non-trivial destructors, destroying consists of calling that destructor.  In the case of pointers, or any other trivially destructible object, destroying consists of doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

> then the assign method would actually delete foo* before copying data to the target indexes.

No, it will only delete pointer itself **but will not delete objects which pointers pointing to.**

You need to be careful when you use raw pointers in STL container. If you dynamically allocates elements in `somevector`, you endup leaking memory.

More practice way is to use smart pointers in STL container, dynamically allocated memory will be de-allocated in below case:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> somevector;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, standard containers containing pointers to objects don't ever call delete on the pointers - you are responsible for doing this if/when necessary. This is why storing pointers is a bad idea.

Comment: Not necessarily a "bad" idea, per se ... but should be done with extreme caution.  Generally speaking, it is going to be a much better idea to wrap the pointers with a smart pointer template (e.g. `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`)